# Java, sending data across an input/output stream

Tags: java, stream

I have written a basic java server-side chat application.
At the moment I am using `DataInputStream` and `readUTF()` and it simply transfers text.

Anyone know the best way to go about sending images alongside (or not alongside) text?

I'm fairly new to java and it's packages so any suggestions are good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For writing image, Use ImageIO:**

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("c:\test\img.png"));
ImageIO.write(img,"png", <out writer variable>);
```

**For Reading image, use ImageIO:**

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(ImageIO.createImageInputStream(<socket input stream variable>));
```

**Note:** `readUTF` won't work because it is for reading UTF bytes

Answer (score 1):

I have only done this several times and in no formal setting. With that said this is most likely **not** the proper way of performing an image transfer over any socket stream so if anyone has any insight on the right way to do it please do share.

In all the data you send back and forth set aside say 128 bytes for a header, this header would contain information about what is in the data that you have sent over.

Say you have Client A and they want to send an image to their friend Client B. Client a sends a packet over containing a message:  "FILE 45000 myimage.bmp" (you should probably find a better way to send the header than starting with FILE, something like the number 2 for sending images and number 1 for sending a message). Send the file size, the name of the file and later on you could get technical and send over a checksum.

Then Client A would start streaming over data all titled with the same header information. Client B would then receive the data and start assembling it as it comes in. If a message comes through that does not start with "FILE" you can determine what to do with that packet (maybe its a text message or something else).

What im going to put here is mostly pseudo code cause i dont really know what your code looks like but it  could look something like this:

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(/*your sockets inputstream*/);
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("c:\\myfile"));

    int numRead = 0;
    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    while((numRead = in.read(bytes)) != -1) {
        String header = new String(bytes, 0, 128);
        if(header.startsWith("TEXT")) {
            // send text to your chat box
            String content = new String(bytes, 128, bytes.length-128);
        } else if(header.startsWith("FILE")) {
            // write the remainder of the file to the harddrive
            out.write(bytes, 128, bytes.length-128);
        }
    }
```

This is all stuff to play around with and make errors and fix. Being new to java is all about trial and error, if you have any more questions please post, or if anyone has any links to proper headings to send or delimiters to put in please link!

Comment: Loving this answer, messing around with it a bit, not working too badly either!

Comment: Yea I used this method to send a 10gb file from my friends computer to mine not to long ago. Theres lots of tinkering with it to get things working well. Im glad you found it useful =D